# Plotly.js cross filtering

Tags: javascript, plotly

Does Plotly.js have any cross filtering functionality (like [dc.js](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/) has)?

Here is what I mean (see example of dc.js cross filtering: https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/)

- Clicking a plot element filters the data such that you are now only looking at the subset of the data represented by that plot element.
- If you click Q1 then you only see data from the first quarter and all the other plots change.
- If you click 'day of the week', for instance 'Monday', you see only data from Monday in Q1.